# Riemann integrability with Peano-Jordan measure

Tags: real-analysis

I have $R=[0,2]\times[0,4]$ and $f:R\to R$.

$f(x,y)= 
\begin{cases}
3,  & \text{if  $x,y \quad {are \quad rational}$ }\\ 
2, & \text{if $x  \quad {is \quad rational} ; y \quad {is \quad irrational}$  }  \\
1, & \text{if $y \quad{ is \quad rational}  ;x \quad {is \quad irrational}$  }  \\
0, & \text{if $x,y \quad {are \quad irrational}$}\\
\end{cases}$

to prove f is Riemann integrable how can I create a partition of R?

Comment: in every partition upper and lower Riemann sum assume different value so f isn't Riemann integrable?

Comment: how can I build upper an lower Riemann sums?